# Assembler - How to end writing a password with ENTER

Tags: assembly, windows-10, nasm, dosbox

I'm doing an assignment for Assembly programming, and I can't get past this problem.
The task is to write a program, in which user types a password, console shows '*' instead of typed letters. After typing said password user presses ENTER which "sets" the password, and requires the user to type the same password again to check if it's the same as set before.

I got this code to work which reads keystrokes, saves typed password and then writes it in the console. But I can't get it to stop on pressed ENTER. (it is set to register only 12 letters now)

```
section .text
org 100h

xor si, si  
mov dl, '*'     

loop:               
    mov ah, 7           
    int 21h
    mov [letters+si], al        
        
    mov ah, 2           
    int 21h             
    inc si
    cmp si, 12
    jnz loop
    
xor si, si
write:
    mov dl, [letters+si]    
    int 21h         
    inc si
    cmp si, 12
    jnz write

end:
    mov ax, 4c00h 
    int 21h
    
section .bss
    letters resb 12
```

Comment: Currently it doesn't seem to contain any code at all that is even trying to stop on ENTER.  What did you try?

Comment: I dont understand assembler at all, so thats what i got, and i tried some solutions from internet. But I got errors or not working as I intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Fetching a very old and dusty book from the bookshelf...)

```
mov ah, 7           
int 21h
```

This reads a letter (without echo) from the console into al. You are storing it in your string afterwards. After these two lines, before you store al, you have to check whether it's the enter key. In DOS, the enter key is represented by two characters, a carriage return and a line feed. You are only interested in either of them, (but you don't want to store them). Carriage return is 0xd, line feed is 0xa. So you need something like

```
cmp al, 0dh
je endOfLoop; // place label before xor si, si
```

Comment: Sorry for making you breath all that dust.
I placed those 2 lines where you said they should be and added label before xor. But after writing like 4-5 letters and presing ENTER it won't show the password, and it's waiting for me to type again 12 letters and then shuts down without showing anything.

Comment: Oh, you're missing to set al before the int 21h command after the write. Insert `mov ah, 2` after the `while` label.

Comment: Oh got it. One more thing. The ENTER thing works fine, but now if i set password shorter than 12 letters, it writes my password + random letters (for example I set password to be 123456 and press ENTER, it reads back "123456d7xc sd") how to clear the remaining characters?

Comment: Run another loop at the start of the program that sets all values in "letters" to zero. You can do that with one of the most powerful assembly commands of the X86 architecture: `xor di, di; xor al, al; mov cx, 12; rep stosb;`

Comment: I did 

`
zeroloop:;
 xor di, di;
 xor al, al;
 mov cx, 12;
 rep stosb;
`

But it's not clearing anything, did i do something wrong?

Comment: @Reppumaru For `rep stosb` to work you need to replace `xor di, di` with `mov di, letters`. This will load the correct address.

Comment: @SepRoland And what letters should be defiend as?

Comment: @Reppumaru *letters* is already defined in your program. It's the address of the 12-byte buffer stored in the .bss section.